# What can be said about the sequence $(\left\Vert A^{n}\left( x\right) \right\Vert ^{\frac{1}{n}})_{n}$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, operator-theory, linear-transformations, spectral-theory

Let $H$ be a separable infinite dimensional Hilbert space and let $A\in B(H)$ be a bounded operator.
For any $x\in H$ is $(\left\Vert A^{n}\left( x\right) \right\Vert ^{\frac{1}{n}})_{n}$ a decreasing and/or a convergent sequence ?
Recall that $\lim \left\Vert A^{n} \right\Vert ^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is the spectral radius of $A$.

Comment: It certainly is not decreasing in general. If the operator is normal, then the sequence will always converge, as can be seen by invoking the spectral theorem and considering the setting of a multiplication operator. But in general, the question seems to be quite hard, as far as I can see :)

Comment: thank you so much. But, I've found that the sequance is bounded by max(1,||x||).||A||